# If isblank(cell) then resume next VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Good afternoon all,

I am writing a code that do the following: find column "x", then find column "y", then in column "z" take the difference between x and y.

In other words, the cell in Z1 will be: X1-Y1 and so on.

Now, the columns x and y are not always values, but there are also dates and empty cells. I maanged to solve the problem with dates and strings by using `on error resume next` so the code just skips it.

But I cant find a way to handle blank cells. I tried to use `if isblank(cell) = true then resume next`

With the code as today, if vba finds a blank cell in x and y, it just takes the difference from 0 to 0, so in column z will be displayed 0, which is not.

The part of the code that gives me problem is this:

```
For z = 1 To lastrow
    For j = rownum + 1 To finalrow

        On Error Resume Next

        ws.Cells(j, lastcol + 2 + z).Value = ws.Cells(j, acol).Value - ws.Cells(j, colnum + z - 1).Value
        ws.Cells(j, lastcol + 2 + z).NumberFormat = "0.0"

    Next j
Next z
```

I would need the code to firstly see if in column x OR y there is a blank cell. If this is the case, then go to next iteration.

I tried to write something like this but it gives me error:

```
For z = 1 To lastrow
    For j = rownum + 1 To finalrow

        On Error Resume Next
        if isblank(ws.Cells(j, lastcol + 2 + z).Value)=true then resume next

        ws.Cells(j, lastcol + 2 + z).Value = ws.Cells(j, acol).Value - ws.Cells(j, colnum + z - 1).Value
        ws.Cells(j, lastcol + 2 + z).NumberFormat = "0.0"

    Next j
Next z

end if
```

The variables are well settled and the code works without any problem (if ran without the isblank statement)

Thank you!

Comment: What is the idea of `Resume Next`? Why do you need it?

Comment: I want the code to skip the iteration because if a cell is blank and it takes the difference from, say, X1=200 and Y1=blank, Z1 will be equal to 200 (200-0), why I just want it to be blank

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
For z = 1 To lastrow
    For j = rownum + 1 To finalrow
        if ws.Cells(j, acol).Value = "" or ws.Cells(j, colnum + z - 1).Value = "" then 
            'One or more Cells are null
        else
            ws.Cells(j, lastcol + 2 + z).Value = ws.Cells(j, acol).Value - ws.Cells(j, colnum + z - 1).Value
            ws.Cells(j, lastcol + 2 + z).NumberFormat = "0.0"
        end if
    Next j
Next z
```

Answer (score 1):

`IsBlank()` does not exist in VBA. It is an Excel function. However, there are plenty of ways to check whether a range is blank. A possible way is to `Trim()` the range and see whether it is equal to `""`:

```
For z = 1 To lastRow
    For j = rownum + 1 To finalrow
        If Trim(ws.Cells(j, lastcol + 2 + z)) = "" Or _
                Not IsNumeric(ws.Cells(j, lastcol + 2 + z)) Then
            ws.Cells(j, lastcol + 2 + z) = ws.Cells(j, acol) - ws.Cells(j, colnum + z - 1)
            ws.Cells(j, lastcol + 2 + z).NumberFormat = "0.0"
        End If
    Next j
Next z
```

As a rule of thumb in VBA - whenever you feel like writing `On Error Resume Next`, most probably there is a better way to write the whole piece, by avoiding it. The `On Error Resume Next` ignores all errors in the code and forces it to continue, thus errors that may appear are ignored.

Comment: thanks @Vityata. As you can see I edited the code above. I need the error resume next because some cells are strings, and without the error resume next the code stops..

Comment: @Saverio - If you want to avoid the strings, make sure that the cells are numeric, before processing them. This is so common, that VBA has introduced a built-in function for this - `IsNumeric()`. See the updated code.